# how to modify user table

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add two fields to the table user. the first name and a key.

on RegisterController

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nom' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'prenom' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'cle' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:users'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $rand = rand(9999, 999999999);
        $cle = 'Pa'.$rand;
        return User::create([
            'nom' => $data['nom'],
            'prenom' => $data['prenom'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'cle' => $cle,
        ]);
    }
```

On user model

```
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'nom', 'prenom', 'email', 'password', 'cle',
    ];
```

table migration

```
{
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('cle')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have no errors, but the registration does not go to the database and I stay on the registration page

Comment: Are you outputting validation errors on your registration blade view correctly, seems like validation may be failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line `'cle' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:users'],` from your `validator()` method, as you're generating *cle* randomely in you `create()` method, and you don't need to receive this parameter.
Maybe you have an invisible error for this field.